# vue.js:how to v-model an object in every it's value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want a effect like this:
when i typing something in <input>,vue could help me format the string.

eg:when someone typting 20160324... ,this can format like "2016-03-24..." at the same time(so this effect must be show in a same <input>),because my expected is "2016-03-24 15:00:00".

ps:

1. my <input> are generate dynamic by an object array.i want konw what the right way to write "v-model" on every item.
2. because of i don't know what the specified <input>,so i cant't watch it by "Vue.$watch".

my data like that below:

```
data{
        form:[
            {name:'name',value:'',inputType:'text'},
            {name:'sex',value:'',inputType:'radio'},
            {name:'age',value:'20',inputType:'text'},
            {name:'time',value:'',inputType:'date'},
        ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first to dynamically generate the form you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/2q3Lt1vr/.

The [type=date] input is rendered as html5 date-picker. So the second example I will change `date` to `text`. You can see here https://jsfiddle.net/dgq01f6u/2/.
The format method depends on your own logic. This demo needs you to unfocus when you finish your type.

If you want to update the input filed on real time, you may need to use `watch` like

```js
watch: {
  form: {
   deep: true,
   handler: function() {
     this.form.forEach(function(field) {
       if (field.inputType === 'date') {
         // do your format  
       }
     });
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!
this can resolve my puzzlement ,your answers achieve my requirement too.
thanks again